Windows 11 still connected to domain after complete format and fresh reinstall
I just created fresh installation media for Windows 11 Pro (x64) from the Microsoft website. I chose a freshly formatted USB and ran the setup from my personal computer (not connected to any domains).
I then used the USB to boot up the Windows setup on an HP laptop which was previously connected to a company domain. I deleted all partitions, and created and formatted new ones.
After the setup ran successfully, it is now prompting me to log in to the company Active Directory and no other options are available to finalize the Windows installation. I can even see the company's logo on the sign-in screen.
I thought the above steps would produce a freshly installed copy of Windows. Does this have something to do with the BIOS?
The company that issued me the laptop no longer exists so going to them for support is not an option. Any advice would be appreciated.

'silly' question - what happens if you install the OS while completely offline?

@JourneymanGeek: Thanks. I downloaded the offline Windows ISO, used Rufus to create a bootable USB (which allowed skipping the Win 11 requirement), and did NOT connect to WiFi until the setup was complete.

Hah. Very very lucky guess on my part and I am glad it worked

I managed to complete the install using the following steps:

Reset the BIOS to factory settings.
Downloaded the offline Windows ISO.
Used Rufus to create a bootable USB (which allowed skipping the Win 11 requirement).
During the setup, I deleted all HDD partitions, created a new one, and formatted it.
Did NOT connect to WiFi until the setup was complete.

In previous attempts, the domain showed up after completing steps 1 through 4. Someone pointed out that since the machine was online in previous attempts, the Microsoft Account Auth mechanism may have picked up the MAC Address on the installed NIC and tied it to a cloud-federated domain.
I do wish that Microsoft had provided a way to stay offline during installation instead of depending on tools like Rufus.
I would appreciate any comments in case I have been misinformed or regarding anything else that may help other users.

You can still install Windows 11 completely off-line without using a Rufus media.  Simply don't put in a network cable and don't connect to Wifi. The standard Microsoft ISO will complain a lot and will try to reconnect after the first reboot during the setup as well, but in the end, if you don't provide any network it will install without one.

@Tonny, when I used the Media Creation tool for USB or the ISO over USB, the WiFi network selection screen simply did not have an option to skip, which of course I thought was odd. Using Rufus, I was able to see the button to skip. Did I miss something?

It could be that Microsoft recently changed some things. I haven't done any recent W11 installs from scratch. Last one was in April. As far as I can remember there was no Skip button initially but I was able to continue without connecting to any Wifi. I think I entered a wrong password for one of the Wifi connections. I don t recall the exact details, but I vaguely l seem to remember that after a few connections errors it eventually gave me a  "Later" or a  "Skip" option.)

@Tonny: You may be right about the option showing up after a few attempts. As distasteful as that approach is, I also doubt that installation would stop dead in its tracks for this reason.

It is also possible there is a difference between Home and Pro/Enterprise versions. I never installed W11 Home actually. (I only use Pro licenses for myself and at the office. The Home versions I deal with for friends and family are all either pre-installed on new hardware or upgrades from W10.)
